# CentOS 6.5 Webmail Server: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to run a webmail server on CentOS with Postfix, Docecot and Roundcube. Whenever I try to send mail or send a test email to my server it fails. I can login so looks like Dovecot is okay.

Here is my server log:

```
Jul  2 14:01:42 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[20154]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory
Jul  2 14:01:42 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[20154]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jul  2 14:01:43 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 20154 exit status 1
Jul  2 14:01:43 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

When I send a test email to my server:

```
Jul  2 14:01:42 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[20154]: connect from mail-ve0-f178.google.com[209.85.128.178]
```

Then it displays the same error as above.

And when I compose mail with Roundcube, it just hangs at `Sending message...` and after a while says `SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed` and the logs  say the same message.

Here is my `postconf -n` output:

```
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = *
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases
virtual_gid_maps = static:2222
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
```

Here is `doveconf -n` output:

```
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab088.4 i686 CentOS release 6.5 (Final) reiserfs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
default_login_user = vmail
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_gid = 2222
first_valid_uid = 2222
listen = *
mail_access_groups = vmail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
passdb {
  args = scheme=SHA1 /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-client {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  process_min_avail = 1
  user = vmail
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = uid=2222 gid=2222 home=/var/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
  driver = static
}
```

And when I do:

```
[root@phantastyc ~]# ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
ls: cannot access /var/spool/postfix/private/auth: No such file or directory
```

### Edit 1

It sort of worked, except there's now a new error message:

```
Jul  3 03:03:14 phantastyc postfix/trivial-rewrite[23348]: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/vmail_domains.db: No such file or directory
Jul  3 03:03:15 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 23348 exit status 1
Jul  3 03:03:15 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Also Google (the server where I sent the test email from) returns a delay error saying the connection to the server was dropped and that it'll keep retrying.

### Edit 2

After fixing the problem above using `postmap`, I ran into another problem.

Here's some logging:

```
Jul  4 21:51:20 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13016]: connect from mail-vc0-f171.google.com[209.85.220.171]
Jul  4 21:51:21 phantastyc postfix/trivial-rewrite[13019]: warning: do not list domain phantastyc.tk in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jul  4 21:51:21 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13016]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-vc0-f171.google.com[209.85.220.171]: 550 5.1.1 <admin@phantastyc.tk>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<bnguyen170@gmail.com> to=<admin@phantastyc.tk> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-vc0-f171.google.com>
Jul  4 21:51:21 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13016]: disconnect from mail-vc0-f171.google.com[209.85.220.171]
```

Not in local table?

Here is `/etc/postfix/vmail_domains`:

```
admin@phantastyc.tk     phantastyc.tk/admin
bnguyen@phantastyc.tk       phantastyc.tk/bnguyen

admin@oa2019.tk         oa2019.tk/admin
bnguyen@oa2019.tk       oa2019.tk/bnguyen
```

What else did I screw up?

### Edit 3

Since the log said I couldn't have the domain name in both `mydestination` and `virtual_mailbox_domains` I removed it from the `mydestination` field and now outgoing mail is fine. Incoming mail is still a little unsteady.

```
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13160]: connect from mail-vc0-f173.google.com[209.85.220.173]
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13160]: 514F213E0E3A: client=mail-vc0-f173.google.com[209.85.220.173]
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/cleanup[13164]: 514F213E0E3A: message-id=<CADZik+X9uC8QGJZtNoWKk_Aw0bdCP49DUVgdWkhVBCZVOuz3cg@mail.gmail.com>
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/qmgr[13153]: 514F213E0E3A: from=<bnguyen170@gmail.com>, size=1930, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/virtual[13165]: 514F213E0E3A: to=<admin@phantastyc.tk>, relay=virtual, delay=0.4, delays=0.32/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/phantastyc.tk/admin: cannot open file: Is a directory)
Jul  4 22:10:41 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13160]: disconnect from mail-vc0-f173.google.com[209.85.220.173]
Jul  4 22:11:08 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13160]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jul  4 22:11:08 phantastyc postfix/smtpd[13160]: 4292A13E0E3B: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=admin@phantastyc.tk
```

This freaks me out:

```
(delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/phantastyc.tk/admin: cannot open file: Is a directory)
```

What's up with that?

Here is `ls /var/vmail/phantastyc.tk/admin`:

```
cur
dovecot.index.log
dovecot.mailbox.log
dovecot.uidlist
dovecot.uidvalidity
dovecot.uidvalidity.53b3965c
new
subscriptions
tmp
```

Here is `/etc/postfix/vmail_domains`:

```
admin@phantastyc.tk     phantastyc.tk/admin
bnguyen@phantastyc.tk       phantastyc.tk/bnguyen

admin@oa2019.tk         oa2019.tk/admin
bnguyen@oa2019.tk       oa2019.tk/bnguyen
```

### Edit 4

Sorry I was rushing ahead of myself. I should've done that first. A simple search found that a trailing slash was missing on the mailbox directory. My mail server now works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like mismatch of dovecot configuration and postfix configuration.

In dovecot configuration (especially in section **service auth**, you just define two socket  **auth-client** and **auth-master**. Add one section `unix_listener` with content

```
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  mode = 0660
  # Assuming the default Postfix user and group
  user = postfix
  group = postfix        
}
```

See [this page](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) for further documentation.

Comment: It sort of worked, except there's now a new error message: `Jul  3 03:03:15 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 23348 exit status 1
| Jul  3 03:03:15 phantastyc postfix/master[18459]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite: bad command startup -- throttling
` Also Google (the server where I sent the test email from) returns a delay error saying the connection to the server was dropped and that it'll keep retrying.

Comment: Did file `/etc/postfix/vmail_domains` exist? Have you run `postmap /etc/postfix/vmail_domains`?

Comment: Thanks for the `postmap` solution. Except we have more problems. See edits above.

Comment: Should I keep editing it or make new threads?

Comment: Well I suggest that you post another question. NOTE: Please invest some time to googling the error message in your problem. Your problem has been asked and answered many times in serverfault or in other forums.

Comment: Sorry I was rushing ahead of myself. I should've done that first. A simple search found that a trailing slash was missing on the mailbox directory. My mail server now works fine. Thanks for your help and sorry if I was really dumb.